# jQuery.ajax() to json url is returning a string instead of a json object

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

I'm having a problem where the data object passed to my complete() callback function is not a json object, but rather is an [Object object]. I can see a string of my json response in data.responseText.

Here is my jQuery .ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    command: "GetBlacklist"
  },
  type: 'POST',
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    messageDiv.append("Error: " + errorThrown + "<br />");
  },
  complete: function(json)
  {
    $('.blacklist textarea').text(json.message);
    messageDiv.append("Blacklist loaded.");
  }
});
```

And here is the response that is being sent:

```
{"message":"success","result":0}
```

It evaluates to valid JSON, and I am sending the correct json content-type headers from the server. Stumped on this one!

Comment: JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation...a JSON object IS a javascript object once the string has been evaluated.

Comment: Right... but by specifying 'dataType', the response should be evaluated automatically, correct? Otherwise, I don't see the point of specifying dataType at all. I have considered that I could evaluate the data.responseText that I'm receiving, but I was under the impression that the data object should be a json object representing the server response.

Comment: check to see what you are getting as response for the Ajax call from the server, you might be double serializing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `complete` callback's signature is `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)`, `jqXHR` gives you  [Object object].

Instead, you should use `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` callback, which will be called if the request succeeds, and this time the `data` will give you the right thing.

More info please check [the manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: [success] seems to be depracated... you should use .done but it does not solve the problem